# How is my model working if all the base layer trainables are set to false?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

This is the model I make for my deep learning project and I am getting decent accuracy out of it. My question is, if I froze the weights of the initial model(which is my base model of VGG19) how did I manage to train the whole model? And also after adding the VGG19 layer with the layers frozen I got better results than I acheived only which a few layers of CNN. Could it be because the weights of the VGG19 were initialized into my CNN layer?

```
img_h=224
img_w=224

initial_model = applications.vgg19.VGG19(weights='imagenet', include_top=False,input_shape = (img_h,img_w,3))
last = initial_model.output

for layer in initial_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False


x = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=1, activation='relu')(last)
x = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, strides=1, activation='relu')(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
x =  (Dropout(0.1))(x)
preds = Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

"Freezing the layers" just means you don't update the weights on those layers when you backpropagate the error. Therefore, you'll just update the weights on those layers that are not frozen, which enables your neural net to learn.

You are adding some layers after VGG. I don't know if this is a common approach, but it totally makes sense that it kind of works, assuming you are interpreting your metrics right.

Your VGG has already been pre-trained on ImageNet, so it's a pretty good baseline for many use-cases. You are basically using VGG as your **encoder**. Then, on the output of this encoder (which we can call **latent representation of your input**), you train a neural net.

I would also try out more *mainstream* transfer learning techniques, where you gradually unfreeze layers starting from the end, or you have gradually smaller learning rate.

Comment: I guess my question wasn't clear enough. I just wanted to to know if the weights custom layers that I added after the base model were initialed randomly by keras or were they being initialized after the start of the training?